# How to select a hidden submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, hidden-field

If a website that has a property to hide a form, how could I be able to press submit? This form has a hidden submit button, but if certain parameters are not correct, it automatically hides this form.

I can see it for a split second until it goes white. I tried firefox inspect element, and it's there, but is there a way to press submit while hidden? I tried pressing tab and hopefully selecting it, but it won't do it.

I'm sure there is a way to basically "push" the submit button while hidden.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the markup of that button/form?

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery that would be

```
$("name_of_form).submit();
```

In vanilla Javascript it should be

```
document.getElementById(id).submit();
```

or

```
document.forms.form_name.submit();
```

Of course, to retrieve the name you'd open up the browser's dev tool, there's usually an arrow you can click to find the element on the page, or just read the html and find it, and then you'll know the name of the form. This is also where you'll run the command.

Here's an example:

```
<form action="/weather/searchauto" method="POST" id="latlongForm">
    <input id="lat" name="lat" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="long" name="long" type="hidden" value="">
</form>
```

So in this case the name is "latlongForm", so you can type in the console:

document.forms.latlongForm.submit()

See if that works!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

So in the Firefox Inspect Element, I see the javascript code

"function submitChanges() {var f = document.PhoneNumberForm; submit1Form(f); } function cancelChanges() { document.location ="PhoneNumber.do; }

Question is, how can I "execute" the submit button with it being blanked out (it's hidden and not visible normally). is there a way in Firefox to "select" it and submit it? I do not have access to the webpage code.

Comment: If the form exists in the HTML, you should be able to find it using Firefox's inspect Element. I personally would just experiment with it.